# HTTPS Request returns getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I am attempting to make an HTTPS POST request to the https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pets endpoint. Documentation can be found here: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/. It works fine using Postman, but when I make the same request, with the same data using Node.js I get the following error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND petstore.swagger.io/v2
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'petstore.swagger.io/v2'
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import * as https from 'https';

async function main()  {

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        name: 'doggie',
        photoUrls: [
            "string"
        ]
    });

    const options = {
        hostname: "petstore.swagger.io/v2",
        path: "/pet",
        body: data
    }

    try {
        let response = await httpRequest(options);
        console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

function httpRequest(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const clientRequest = https.request(options, incomingMessage => {

            // Response object.
            let response = {
                statusCode: incomingMessage.statusCode,
                headers: incomingMessage.headers,
                body: []
            };

            // Collect response body data.
            incomingMessage.on('data', chunk => {
                response.body.push(chunk);
            });

            // Resolve on end.
            incomingMessage.on('end', () => {
                if (response.body.length) {

                    response.body = response.body.join();

                    try {
                        response.body = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    } catch (error) {
                        // Silently fail if response is not JSON.
                    }
                }

                resolve(response);
            });
        });
        
        // Reject on request error.
        clientRequest.on('error', error => {
            reject(error);
        });

        // Write request body if present.
        if (options.body) {
            clientRequest.write(options.body);
        }

        // Close HTTP connection.
        clientRequest.end();
    });
}

main();
```

What am I messing up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host name contains only the domain, not the rest of the path. You also need to provide the HTTP method and the content type.

```
    const options = {
        hostname: "petstore.swagger.io",
        path: "/v2/pet",
        body: data,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly says about https. I have seen such errors while running tests in webdriverio.
Just try removing the Http  and keep only the domain name.

`hostname: 'xyz.sample.io', port: , path: '/wd/hub',`